# Which tool better to load data into cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

We will be using cassandra to store .csv and unstructured data in our project.
The data can be into GBs. So I want to know which is better way or tools to load data into Cassandra.
SSTables can handle so much of data?
Or I should go for tools like spark or YCSB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm a ScyllaDB employee)

SStables can store this size of data easy (and also much more...)

If you have your data in SStable format than I would highly recommend using the SStableLoader utility.
Running without any parameters will present the list of options and usage. Most important are the sstables directory and the node IP.
I recommend using the -x flag for prepared statements, as it boosts the performance.

Examples:

- `sstableloader -x -d [node IP] .../[ks]/[table]`
- `sstableloader -x -d [node IP] .../[mount point] (in /[ks]/[table] format)`

Another option is to use the Bulk copy. For example: `copy keyspace1.table1 FROM 'a.csv'  WITH HEADER=TRUE;`

I recommend you read this [blog](http://www.scylladb.com/2017/04/13/storing-retrieving-large-data-sets-scylla-1-6-vs-cassandra-3-0-9/) about ingestion rates of large datasets in Cassandra and Scylla.
Another [blog](http://www.scylladb.com/2017/12/19/migrating-to-scylla/) you can find interesting is about loading data from various DB architectures.

Good luck and happy loading.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to implement SSTables into my project.